# Limitar índices de um Array

Tags: javascript, array

Como posso **limitar** o número de **valores/índices** de um **array**? Por exemplo:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr)
// Exibirá: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Objetivo:

```
//Reduzindo o limite de índices do array para 2:
console.log(arr)
// Exibirá: [1, 2]
```

Tem alguma maneira simples de realizar isso? Sem utilizar *estruturas de repetição* ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr.slice(0, 2)); // [1, 2]
```

O método `slice` recebe dois parâmetros: o índice inicial e o final, sendo que o inicial é incluso e o final não. Como em arrays os índices começam em zero, se eu quero apenas os dois primeiros, eu uso `slice(0, 2)`, pois assim os índices zero e 1 são inclusos.

Lembrando ainda que os parâmetros são opcionais. Se o índice final é omitido, ele pega até o final do array. E se o inicial é omitido, ele pega tudo desde o início do array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// começa do índice 2 (ou seja, do número 3), até o final do array
console.log(arr.slice(2)); // [3, 4]

// começa do índice 0 até o final do array (ou seja, o array todo)
console.log(arr.slice()); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Lembrando sempre que `slice` [retorna um novo array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Return_value). Portanto, chamar `slice()` sem argumentos é uma das maneiras de se [criar uma cópia do array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286982).

---

Se quiser sempre pegar os N primeiros elementos do array, outra alternativa é mudar o seu tamanho, setando a [propriedade `length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.length = 2; // muda o tamanho do array para 2
console.log(arr); // [1, 2]
```

Lembrando que esta opção sempre vai pegar somente os N primeiros elementos. Se quiser ser mais flexível (por exemplo, pegar do terceiro até o décimo elemento), use `slice`.